# Deleted local repo after using git filter-repo

Tags: git

so I used

```
git filter-repo --path example/path/to/something--invert-paths --force
```

and my repo and all the refs where deleted. I have a remote branch out the last push was about a month ago so there was quite some progress lost.

Is there any way to restore what has been lost?

Comment: There is a reason [why `git filter-repo` declines to run unless it's running on a freshly cloned repository](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#FRESHCLONE). Yet you disabled that using `--force`. I think you'll have a very hard time recovering anything, but I wish you luck.

Comment: Use `tree .git/refs` to see what refs you have (maybe `refs/replace`? I don’t know git-filter-repo that well). If you have all your objects then you can try to reconstruct the history manually.

Comment: Also: if you are using an IDE, then *that* might be able to help you recover at least the last state of your code, because they often track local history (in addition to whatever VCS you use)

Comment: @JoachimSauer Perfect that exactly helped me. Found a Version i could revert to in my ide. Thanks a lot